# How to get unique ID of Bluetooth Device using Core Bluetooth in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I am developing an application that requires the ios device to provide Bluetooth UUID (to get the Bluetooth UUID from scanned/connected device), then send it to the server for further development. I can not find any answer on the internet.

I am using core bluetooth for scanning and connecting device and sent device info name and uuid but uuid changed every 15-20 minutes. How can i recognize previously connected device and how can i get unique BLE device **UUID** so that i can match identifier with previously added device list. *Help please*...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `identifier` property of the discovered `CBPeripheral` and connect to that. If you connect then the identifier should not change for that device for a significant amount of time (in practice I don't think it ever changes, but in theory it can).

Once you have a peripherals identifier you can save that value and subsequently get the peripheral via [`retrievePeripherals`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals) rather than scanning.

The issue you will face is that the `identifier` is specific to the iOS device that discovers the peripheral. Another iOS device will get a different identifier for the same peripheral.

If you need a unique identifier for your peripheral that is transportable across iOS devices then you will need to expose such a value via a characteristic on the peripheral itself and have your app read that characteristic value after it has connected.

Comment: Ok @Paulw11 Thanks. I have saved BLE identifiers to back-end database and i am able to search BLE device with  retrievePeripherals but when i am trying to connect it error occurred name with "API MISUSE: Cancelling connection for unused peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x280bfd9a0, identifier = 3A025596-F553-9022-9F85-9E12075D8ADE, name = iPhone, state = connecting>, Did you forget to keep a reference to it?"

Comment: As the error says, you need to keep a strong reference to the CBPeripheral instance; ie in a property, not just a local variable.

Comment: let getData = self.centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: ids)

if getData.count > 0 {
               

if getData[0].identifier.uuidString == self.carsList[i].bluetooth_identifier{
 getData[0].delegate = self
                           //     self.centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(getData[0])

                                self.centralManager.connect(getData[0], options: nil)
}
}
}

when i comment self.centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection line it gives not any error. but didConnect peripheral function not called.

Comment: `getData` is a local variable. As soon as that closure or function exits it will be released, which is what the warning is telling you. You need to hold a strong reference to the peripheral in a property.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can  I do this.

Comment: Can I get connected device list in iOS App. For eg if my car bluetooth is ON and when i turn ON my phone's bluetooth it will auto connects to car's bluetooth. Is there any way to get connected device info or connected list in App?

Comment: Your cars Bluetooth will appear as an available audio device in the av framework. As it is legacy bluetooth it isn't visible via Core Bluetooth

Comment: Do you have code and example of this?Please share with me.

Answer (score -1):

To add custom advertisement data to iOS Bluetooth, you can follow these steps:

Create an NSMutableDictionary object to store the advertisement data. This dictionary will be used to configure the data included in the advertisement.

Add your custom advertisement data to the dictionary. You can use specific keys to identify your custom data, and the values can be strings, byte arrays, or other basic data types.

`NSMutableDictionary *advertisementData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; [advertisementData setObject:@"CustomData"forKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];`

In the example above, we added custom data "CustomData" as the local name (CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) in the advertisement.

Call the startAdvertising: method and pass the advertisement data dictionary as a parameter.

`[peripheralManager startAdvertising:advertisementData];`

This will start the Bluetooth advertisement and include your custom advertisement data in the broadcast.

Please note that iOS devices have a limit on the length of the advertisement data, typically 31 bytes. If you add too much custom data, it may exceed the limit and the advertisement may not be broadcasted properly. Therefore, ensure that your custom advertisement data fits within the limits of the advertisement packet.

In addition to custom advertisement data, you can also add other standard advertisement data such as service UUIDs, appearance data, etc. Choose the keys and corresponding values to add based on your requirements. Refer to the documentation of the CoreBluetooth framework for available advertisement keys and their requirements.

These are the basic steps to add custom advertisement data. Depending on your needs, you can add different types of custom data and transmit them through Bluetooth advertisement.